# Not fetching the javascript

Tags: knockout.js

In commerce cloud we are using the KnockoutJs to fetch the contents. Below code is written above html code, since below code is failing not able to display the html content.

How to fix this ? It is working fine in another instance

```
<!-- ko if: initialized() && $data.hasOwnProperty('product-configure') -->
<!-- ko with: $data['product-configure'] -->
```

Comment: can you mention that where above code is ? and also above html !
please post code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There are two conditions on your code snippet:

- initialized() must be true
- $data must exist (on your viewmodel or global?) and must have the property "product-configure"

So I guess you need to put something like this above the code:

```
<pre data-bind="text: 'Initialized:' + initialized()"></pre>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data,null, 2)"></pre>
```

To have the both conditions displayed to see which one is failing and take further actions. If the page loads data over ajax you should check your network requests to see if one request might be failing, which could be the reason for the data not being loaded.